# Careers does not recognise my Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, jobs

When I go to my Careers profile to associate Stack Exchange sites and add answers, it does not recognise any of my Stack Exchange accounts. No options show up at all for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two accounts, and your other account was linked to your network accounts. I've merged them and you should be all set.

Comment: I have this same problem: Can you please merge mine as well?  Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnRuiz Yup, you had two accounts as well; now merged.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Hate to jump on the me to bandwagon, but I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Si. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @KorneelBouman I have the same problem. Not sure why that happend I juse for login just one openid account and a *other* login method.

Comment: @rekire Sometimes it takes a day or so for everything to sync up, but it looks like you're all set